# Averaging values in a matrix to a new matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have been checking SO but I haven't found an answer that let me understand how to do this.... Thanks in advance for your help.

I need to average values in a matrix according to an ID... For example (but I have a 4000 by 4000...):

```
        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]
[1,]    NA         A         B        C       B
[2,]     A       11.0     10.0      8.0      4.0
[3,]     B        6.0     10.0     15.0      5.0
[4,]     C       12.0     11.0     10.0      4.0
[5,]     B       12.0     11.0     10.0      5.0
```

I expect a result like:

```
        [,1]    [,2]      [,3]    [,4]
[1,]     NA       A        B        C  
[2,]     A       11.0     7.0      8.0      
[3,]     B        9.0     7.8     12.5         
[4,]     C       12.0     7.5     10.0
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You must have created a matrix in a wrong way.  The 1st column would be the row names and 1st row the column names.  Now, it would be a character matrix.

Comment: OP is using the first row/col as names instead of colnames and rownames in the example. The answer to the question is to use the aggregate function I believe

Comment: Why your (B,B) is 10.5?  Why your (C,B) is 7.5?

Comment: I think I understand where (C,B) come from, but I'm having a hard time coming up with (B, B). I'm getting 7.75 ((10+11+5+5)/4) and it looks like you are averaging only the column values (I.e. 11 and 10)

Comment: B, B is 7.75 (approx 7.8, Sorry I was wrong.). I am unsure whether I can use repeated names (e.g. B in the example above) as row/col names. Can I?

Comment: I do not understand how for example the value (A, A) 11.0 is calculated... I would try to transform the matrix to a data.table / data.frame, perhaps using melting/casting from `reshape2` package to get it work.

Comment: @Marco, is row 1 exactly the same as column 1 as you have in your example? FYI, you can use the "@" symbol, followed by a user's name to get their attention.

Answer (score 1):

As @akrun pointed out, it isn't a good idea to label your rows and columns with actual rows and columns in the matrix. The reason for this is because you cannot mix data types in matrices (see [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matrix.html) for more information). Instead, you can use `rownames/colnames` to label your matrix. Below, is a very simple base R solution.  I'm sure there is a much faster way using `data.table` or `dplyr`, but this will do.  Note, this will be pretty slow if the number of unique ID's is larger than a 1000 or so.

```
AverageMatVals <- function(mat) {  ## This way is very natural but highly inefficient
    uniRow <- unique(rownames(mat))
    uniCol <- unique(colnames(mat))
    newmat <- matrix(numeric(0), nrow=length(uniRow), ncol=length(uniCol))
    rownames(newmat) <- uniRow
    colnames(newmat) <- uniCol

    for (i in 1:nrow(newmat)) {
        rowMatch <- which(rownames(mat)==uniRow[i])
        for (j in 1:ncol(newmat)) {
            colMatch <- which(colnames(mat)==uniCol[j])
            newmat[i,j] <- round(mean(mat[rowMatch,colMatch]), 1)
        }
    }
    newmat
}    

mat <- matrix(c(11,6,12,12,10,10,11,11,8,15,10,10,4,5,4,5), nrow=4)
rownames(mat) <- c("A","B","C","B")
colnames(mat) <- c("A","B","C","B")

AverageMatVals(mat)
   A    B    C
A 11  7.0  8.0
B  9  7.8 12.5
C 12  7.5 10.0
```

Below is a much faster approach that should perform well on matrices with more than 5,000 rows/columns or so.

```
AverageMatValsFast <- function(mat) {
    uniRow <- unique(rownames(mat))
    uniCol <- unique(colnames(mat))
    lenRow <- length(uniRow)
    v1 <- rep(1, ncol(mat))
    v2 <- rep(1, lenRow)

    tempMat <- t(vapply(1:lenRow, function(x) {
            rowMatch <- which(rownames(mat)==uniRow[x])
            if (length(rowMatch)>1) {
                colMeans(mat[rowMatch,])
            } else {
                mat[rowMatch,]
            }}, v1))

    meanMat <- vapply(1:length(uniCol), function(x) {
                colMatch <- which(colnames(mat)==uniCol[x])
                if (length(colMatch)>1) {
                    round(rowMeans(tempMat[,colMatch]), 1)
                } else {
                    round(tempMat[,colMatch], 1)
                }}, v2)

    remove(tempMat)    ## This could be a very large 
    gc()               ## object thus we need to clean it up
    rownames(meanMat) <- uniRow
    colnames(meanMat) <- uniCol

    meanMat
}
```

Below are some timings:

```
set.seed(13379)
matTest1 <- matrix(sample(10^6, 4000^2, replace = TRUE), nrow = 4000, ncol = 4000)
myLetters <- expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
myLetters <- sapply(1:nrow(myLetters), function(x) paste(myLetters[x, ],collapse=""))
rownames(matTest1) <- sample(myLetters, 4000, replace = TRUE)
colnames(matTest1) <- sample(myLetters, 4000, replace = TRUE)

system.time(a <- AverageMatValFast(matTest1))
 user  system elapsed 
 0.77    0.00    0.77

system.time(b <- AverageMatVal(matTest1))
  user  system elapsed 
 59.50    0.02   59.56

all(sapply(1:nrow(a), function(x) all(abs(a[x,]-b[x,])<0.2)))   ## can't test equality b/c of rounding
[1]  TRUE
```

Here is a very large example:

```
set.seed(11)
matTest2 <- matrix(sample(10^6, 6000^2, replace = TRUE), nrow = 6000, ncol = 6000)
myLetters <- expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS[sample(26,5)], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
myLetters <- sapply(1:nrow(myLetters), function(x) paste(myLetters[x, ],collapse=""))
rownames(matTest2) <- sample(myLetters, 6000, replace = TRUE)
colnames(matTest2) <- sample(myLetters, 6000, replace = TRUE)

system.time(t1 <- AverageMatValFast(matTest2))
 user  system elapsed 
 3.54    0.04    3.58 

dim(t1)
[1]  2836  2831
```

**Update**

Below is an example like the OP suggest in the comments. The names were obtained freely [here](http://www.quietaffiliate.com/free-first-name-and-last-name-databases-csv-and-sql/).

```
set.seed(333)
myNames <- read.csv("http://www.quietaffiliate.com/Files/CSV_Database_of_First_Names.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
myNames <- tolower(myNames$firstname)

length(myNames)
[1] 5494

head(myNames)
[1] "aaron" "aaron" "abbey" "abbie" "abby"  "abdul"

sampNames1 <- sample(myNames, 4000, replace = TRUE)
sampNames2 <- sample(myNames, 4000, replace = TRUE)

mat1 <- matrix(sample(10^6, 4000^2, replace = TRUE), nrow = 4000, ncol = 4000)
rownames(mat1) <- sampNames1
colnames(mat1) <- sampNames2

system.time(t2 <- AverageMatValsFast(mat1))
  user  system elapsed 
  2.32    0.19    2.51

t2[1:10, 1:5]
              wen  cristen  sherell     sona    denna
jovan    624688.0 141679.5 551442.5 568128.8 405943.2
benjamin 662494.2 658096.5 435062.5 521144.0 424704.8
wendolyn 869093.5 856608.0 446543.5 715201.0 234873.5
liane    495856.0 615054.0 456647.5 304897.0 509781.5
alexia   430558.0 369075.0 724121.0 617018.0 404110.5
nobuko   302176.5 249807.0 664577.0 458983.5 416712.5
lynsey   583306.0 247513.7 466308.2 384851.2 569038.0
eunice   503505.3 410133.0 304032.3 354720.7 415618.0
arnita   667288.5 388770.0 661687.0 368347.0 495238.5
eugenia  572900.2 568346.5 613246.2 525411.1 482589.8
```

Comment: @Marco, I fixed an entry error from yesterday. I didn't have access to internet, thus I was forced to enter all of my code through my phone.  This proved to be more difficult than actually coming up with the solution :). Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The functions are great. I have a minor problem using my old custom labels ("bob", "dave", "jason", "william", ...), which appears to give problems when given thru 

    rownames(mat1) <- c("bob", "dave", "jason", "william", ...) 

because the actual matrix is 2000 x 2000....

Comment: @Marco, could you expound on your issues with assigning `rownames` to a matrix.  From what I can tell, `rownames(mat1) <- c("bob", "dave", "jason", "william", ...)` should work just fine.  See my updated code. I hope this helps!